# How to delete table cells properly

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete table rows and table column. For that i have written two functions. The DelelteRow() and DeleteColumn() delete the cells which have 
index greater then zero. But actually one row or column should be deleted at a time. can some one modify my code.

DeleteRow:

```
function DeleteRows() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable'), 
        lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 1,           
        i;
    for (i = lastRow; i > 0; i--) {
        tbl.deleteRow(i);
    }
}
```

DeleteColumn:

```
function DeleteColumns() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('myTable'),
        lastCol = tbl.rows[0].cells.length - 1,
        i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
        for (j = lastCol; j > 0; j--) {
            tbl.rows[i].deleteCell(j);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If only one should be deleted at a time, remove the loop over all rows/columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will delete one row/column at a time. Your question is not entirely clear which row/column you'd like removed, but your code implies you only want the last row/column removed.

```js
var delRowBtn = document.querySelector('.delRow');
delRowBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteLastRow);

var delColBtn = document.querySelector('.delCol');
delColBtn.addEventListener('click', deleteLastColumn);

var tbl = document.querySelector('table');

function deleteLastRow() {
  tbl.deleteRow(tbl.rows.length - 1);
}

function deleteLastColumn() {
  var lastCol = tbl.rows[0].cells.length - 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
    tbl.rows[i].deleteCell(lastCol);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  font-size: 24px;
}

table {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

td {
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px solid lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<button class="delRow">Delete Row</button>
<button class="delCol">Delete Column</button>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>r0c0</td>
      <td>r0c1</td>
      <td>r0c2</td>
      <td>r0c3</td>
      <td>r0c4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r1c0</td>
      <td>r1c1</td>
      <td>r1c2</td>
      <td>r1c3</td>
      <td>r1c4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>r2c0</td>
      <td>r2c1</td>
      <td>r2c2</td>
      <td>r2c3</td>
      <td>r2c4</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any how i have correct my code by above comment. Thanks for the reply@Darren